# OR operator inside Selection.Find.Execute statement

Tags: vba, ms-word

I had same question recently but perhaps I added too much of detail then. I only want to focus on the 'OR' operator with the Selection.Find.Execute statement which works fine if I only search for a single thing, i.e. in below example if I try to find either comma or a period, but if I try to use OR operator to check any of these two possibilities i.e. comma or a period, Word VBA gives me type mismatch error.

This works fine:

```
Selection.Find.Execute "*,", , , True
```

This gives type mismatch error:

```
Selection.Find.Execute "(*,)" Or "(*.)", , , True
```

Please suggest a workaround.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Of course! Computers don't "think" like humans. Presuming that your code works without the `OR`, assign the result of each search

```
Selection.Find.Execute "(*,)", , , True
and
Selection.Find.Execute "(*.)", , , True
```

to a variable and apply your `OR` logic to the two results.

Comment: Hi Variatus, Thanks for your feedback. In VBA there are many cases where you can use logical operators and for this reason I had a doubt which is very much clarified with your help.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in that [other discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53796531/3077495) to which you refer: it is *not possible* to use `OR` or `AND` as part of Word's `Find` functionality. It's simply not supported. Either the search term must be able to find all variations (which is sometimes possible) or two separate searches need to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you could use a single *wildcard* Find expression:

```
Selection.Find.Execute "(*[,.])", , , True
```